# How get the meaning of a word in all language using google translate?

Tags: php, google-translate

How to get the meaning of a word in all language represented in english using google translate? For eg., If the input if Lion(English), then the output should be,

```
leon(Spanish)
lion(French)
singam(Tamil)
simhah(Hindi)
```

and so on.

Comment: From: http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html

"Google Translate API v2 is now available as a paid service only, and the number of requests your application can make per day is limited." Are you willing to pay for the API? If not you might as well close this question.

Comment: Its OK Alain i am ready to pay

Comment: Okay, next - what programming language are you using. You haven't tagged your question with any languages. The answer is different depending on whether you're using C++, C#, Java, VB.Net, Go, Google Web Toolkit, JavaScript, Objective C, PHP, Python, or Ruby.

Comment: I am going to implement it in PHP

Answer (score 1):

Use the example from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/translate/simple.php):

```
<?php
require_once '../../src/apiClient.php';
require_once '../../src/contrib/apiTranslateService.php';

$client = new apiClient();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Translate PHP Starter Application');

// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=translate to generate your
// client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
// $client->setDeveloperKey('insert_your_developer_key');
$service = new apiTranslateService($client);

$langs = $service->languages->listLanguages();
print "<h1>Languages</h1><pre>" . print_r($langs, true) . "</pre>";

$translations = $service->translations->listTranslations('Hello', 'hi');
print "<h1>Translations</h1><pre>" . print_r($translations, true) . "</pre>";
```

`listTranslations` gives you the information you seek.

I also recommend reading the documentation, since it's brief: [code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/using_rest.html](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/using_rest.html)